# GridView link column

Tags: vb.net, gridview, hyperlink

I have a vb.net application in which I want the value of a cell in a grid.

am trying with

```vb
Dim a0 = statusGrdvw.Rows(assign).Cells(0).Text
```

where statusGrdvw.Rows(assign).Cells(0).Text is a link am not getting the text of that cell. except that link cell all other ordinary cell am able to get the value. How can I get  the value of that link cell?

Comment: Have you made sure that `assign` is within range?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
DirectCast(statusGrdvw.Rows(assign).Cells(0).Controls(0), HyperLink)).Text
```